# How to apply type to a ObjectConstructor in Typescript in .tsx files

Tags: typescript

I have custom object constructor for object.keys,.values and I can use them without problem in .ts files but in .tsx files compiler thinks it is JSX and gives me error.

```
const myObject = (<TypedObject>Object).keys()
```

Usual tricks with adding comma or extending type with {} or unknown does not work.

Comment: try to add comma `,`. Like here: `(<TypedObject,>Object).keys()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by creating generic functions that return Object.(keys|values|entries) so I can use them anywhere I want.

```
export const typedObjectKeys = <T>(object: T): KeysReturnType<T> =>
  (<TypedObject>Object).keys(object);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't have **angle bracket type assertions**in `tsx`. You need to use the [`as`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsx.html#the-as-operator) operator.